# Smaller font character on some browser

Tags: css, fonts

I'm using a font in my website, but I'm facing a rendering problem. On Apple machines the "t" letter is rendered with the correct height

[right height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAhRu.png)

while on windows machines (and only for smaller font sizes) it gets weird.

[wrong height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MugN.png)

What could it be?

Comment: You should use rem or em for fonts.

Comment: You can't do anything about operating system differences in font rendering. Other than choose fonts that suit your purpose, of course. Some fonts may include instructions for better rendering by Windows as well, but generally speaking Windows font rendering sucks big time compared to what OS X (or macOS) does.

Comment: Thanks all. It seems like that using only .woff and .woff2 font was the problem. I also added .otf files to CSS and now it works perfectly on every plaftorm.